# When to migrate to Asp.net Core from Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, asp.net-core, architecture

Backgroud:

I want to make an informed decision about upgrading our application from the existing Dotnet framework to Dotnet Core.

The application is Asp.net based application hosted on IIS.

Current application project structure of the FA applications:

FASolution

- FA.Utility - Dotnet framework 4.5
- FA.Service - Dotnet framework 4.5 (depends on FA.Utility)
- FA.Website - Asp.net MVC Dotnet framework 4.7 (depends on FA.Service)

Lifetime of the app: Foreseable future. The idea is keep upgrading the app.

What I want to achive?

Technology upgrade wishlist:
        - Fully containarised CI
        - Host the application in Azure/AWS
        - Expose a web api endpoint

Scenario A:

FASolution

- FA.Utility - Dotnet framework 4.5
- FA.Service - Dotnet core (depends on FA.Utility)
- FA.Website - Asp Dotnet core(depends on FA.Service)

Scenario B:

FASolution

- FA.Utility - Dotnet core
- FA.Service - Dotnet framework 4.5 (depends on FA.Utility)
- FA.Website - Asp Dotnet core(depends on FA.Service)

Questions:

1. Is it worth upgrading to .net core and why?
2. Should I upgrade all the above three projects to target Dotnet core at once?
3. 'FA.Utility' for example is referencing third party libraries. Is this going to causing issues during upgrading?
4. Can the two frameworks coexist in production for both Scenario A and Scenario B, and if so can you foresee any issues?

Comment: If you want to mix technology stack in your solution you need to consider dotnet standard library in order to be able reference them in .Net Framework & .Net Core applications. As for dependencies it can cause the issue if they don't have a build for .Net core; From my personal experience, don't create .net core project for not executable code, like dll/libraries, target dot net standard.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question "Is it worth upgrading to .net core and why?"

Microsoft maintains both runtime for building applications with .NET, and they share many of the same APIs. This shared API is what is called the .NETStandard.

[image]

.NET Core is used to create server applications that run on Windows, Linux and Mac. It does not currently support creating desktop applications with a user interface.

Developers Should Use .NET Core When

A cross-platform and open-source framework, it can be used to develop applications on any platform. Often it is used for cloud applications or refactoring large enterprise applications into microservices.

when should you use it? When..

1. There are cross-platform needs. Use it when the application needs to run across multiple platforms such as Windows, Linux and macOS. Those operating systems are supported as development workstations (and the list of supported operating systems is growing):

   - Visual Studio can be used on Windows with a new limited version on the macOS.
   - Visual Studio Code can be used on Windows, Linux and macOS.
   - The command line can be used on all supported platforms.
2. Microservices are being used.
3. When Docker containers are being used.
4. If you have high performance and scalable system needs.
5. If you are running multiple .NET versions side-by-side.
6. If you want command line interface (CLI) control.

Second question "Should I upgrade all the above three projects to target Dotnet core at once?"

In my opinion, if the platform is continuously evolving and will be there in future, Upgrade all your app in dot net core.

Third question "'FA.Utility' for example is referencing third party libraries. Is this going to causing issues during upgrading?"

Since dot net core is upgrading and evolving, it might be possible that it doesn't have support for the third party library, so upgrade FA.Utility project when you are sure that the thrid party libraries are supported by dot net core.

fourth question "Can the two frameworks coexist in production for both Scenario A and Scenario B, and if so can you foresee any issues?"

Yes it can coexist.

Hope it helps.